# XLS - Copy & Paste in VBA - PasteSpecial Method Fails

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with a nagging issue.  I am trying to simply copy and paste a collection of cell forumlas in an XLS worksheet using VBA.  The worksheet (wks1) is created and populated from an AccessDB and is working fine otherwise.

Error: "PasteSpecial Method of Range Class Failed"

```
wks1.Range("P5:S5").Copy
wks1.Range("P5:S10").PasteSpecial _
       Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, _
       Operation:=xlNone, _
       SkipBlanks:=False, _
       Transpose:=False
```

I've attempted a number of variations, but keep bumping into this err msg.

Any suggestions to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
wks1.Range("P5:S5").Autofill  wks1.Range("P5:S10")
```

or

```
wks1.Range("P5:S10").formula = wks1.Range("P5:S5").Formula
```

For the paste special, it has been my experience that less is more:

```
wks1.Range("P5:S5").Copy
wks1.Range("P5:S10").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

But when only values or formulas are wanted why include the clipboard?  It is faster and cleaner to just assign them directly.  So I would use the copy/paste when more than the values or formulas are wanted.

Comment: (upped) for the very nice second option. Can you add a version using pastespecial?

Comment: Hi Scott, Both options work great in this context.  I'm still curious about the cut & paste issue in general - but I am happy to put off additional investigation until the NEXT time I need it. :)  - Thanks again!

Comment: @whytheq See edit, but as I explained I would use the second method instead when wanting only formulas or values.

Comment: The PasteSpecial example posted by Scott produces the same error message as noted above.

Comment: @MarkPelletier it works for me.  I wonder if you have something it those formulas that it does not like.

Comment: Scott, not sure.  They are most basic formulae - simple math based on adjacent cells.  Moving on with your autofill approach! :)